# refetchIntervalInBackground does not stop a query with refetchInterval from refetching in background

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am trying to run a query on a regular interval basis, but not when the page is out of focus.

As I understand from react-query's API (https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery), all I need to do is to add a `refetchIntervalInBackground` flag to the query to stop the regular refetches in the background:

`refetchIntervalInBackground: boolean Optional If set to true, queries that are set to continuously refetch with a refetchInterval will continue to refetch while their tab/window is in the background`

However, this flag is not stopping the query from updating when i defocus the page.

Here is my code (also runnable on https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-shtern-n7jo9?file=/src/index.tsx):

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider, useQuery } from "react-query";

const App = () => {
  const newQuestionsQuery = useQuery("new", () => new Date().toLocaleString(), {
    refetchInterval: 1000,
    refetchIntervalInBackground: false
  });

  return <div>{newQuestionsQuery.data}</div>;
};

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This code runs the query regardless of whether the page is focused or not.

Am I missing something obvious here? How do I disable the query from updating in the background (the window is not focused)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to shift focus to another tab/window/app for 'react-query' to consider the app inactive, one need to make sure that it is not **visible**, so when I opened the devtools window, it was still considered active as it was visible. To test the inactivity behaviour, detach the devtools window, and hide the app, in this case the network requests will stop:

> ***TkDodo:*** we use the provided focusManager, which listens to the visibilitychange and focus events of the browser. The browser emits those if you switch to a different tab. But I've seen these events not being emitted when I have two windows next to each other and I just focus the other window, because then it's not in the "background".

> if that behaviour doesn't suit your case, you can always override the events of the focusManger, and refetchIntervalInBackground will adhere to this.

Full discussion: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/2953